# Set the Priority for two different "after insert" triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create triggers by functionality, instead of DML operation.

For example, I have 2 triggers A and B. A is for `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE`, and B is for `AFTER INSERT`.

How can I know which one (A or B) is run first after insert of a new record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger's will be executed in *undefined order*. But you can set the order of firing through [`sp_settriggerorder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx) inbuilt procedure.

```
sp_settriggerorder @triggername= 'Triggername', @order='First', @stmttype = 'Insert';
```